# Find most frequent string in a binary file C

Tags: c, arrays, string, binary

The purpose of this program is to ask user input for how many exams will be entered into a binary file. When we get user input, e.g. 5, the do while loop asks for input of the name of the course in which the exam was taken and the grade that was received. This gets written in the exams.bin and opened for reading and finding the occurrence of a user inputted keyword for an exam which grade average should be calculated. It finds the grades for that specific course, adds them up and divides them with the number of students that took the exam (the number of recurrence of the name of course). It then prints out a float. And this all works in the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char courseName[30];
    int grade;
} exam;

int main()
{
    exam firstExam, secondExam;
    int examNumber, i = 1, j = 1, gradeSum = 0, studentNumber = 0, mostFreq = 0;
    float gradeAverage;
    char subjectName[30];
    char mostFrequent[30];
    FILE *pointerBinExam = NULL;
    char fileName[13] = "exams.bin";

    pointerBinExam = fopen(fileName, "w+b");

    if(pointerBinExam == NULL)
    {
        printf("File doesn't exist!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("How many exams will you input: ");
    scanf("%d", &examNumber);
    fflush(stdin);

    do{
    printf("\nCourse name: ");
    fgets(firstExam.courseName, 30, stdin);
    printf("\nGrade: ");
    scanf("%d", &firstExam.grade);
    fwrite(&firstExam, sizeof(exam), 1, pointerBinExam);
    fflush(stdin);
    i++;
    }while(i < examNumber+1);

    rewind(pointerBinExam);

    printf("\nInput the name of the course you wish to calculate grade average: ");
    fgets(subjectName, 30, stdin);

    do{
        fread(&secondExam, sizeof(exam), 1, pointerBinExam);

        if (strncmp(subjectName, secondExam.courseName, 30) == 0){
            gradeSum += secondExam.grade;
            studentNumber += 1;
        }

        j++;
    }while(j < examNumber+1);

    gradeAverage = (float)gradeSum/studentNumber;


    printf("\nNumber of students who took the exam: %d\n", studentNumber);
    printf("\nGrade average: %f", gradeAverage);

    studentNumber = 0;

    rewind(pointerBinExam);
    strcpy(mostFrequent, secondExam.courseName);

    rewind(pointerBinExam);

    do{
        fread(&secondExam, sizeof(exam), 1, pointerBinExam);
        if (strncmp(mostFrequent, secondExam.courseName, 30) == 0){
            mostFreq += 1;
            studentNumber += 1;
        }

        j++;
    }while(j < examNumber+1);**

    fclose(pointerBinExam);

    return 0;
}
```

The last part of the code, the new do while loop is not a good approach for my problem. My goal is to put the pointer at the beginning of the binary file and read it again. It should find the most frequent course name in the binary. How should I go about doing this? Is there a command I'm unaware of, or should this be handled with a 2D array that sorts the strings in the binary. I'm clueless and only beginning to understand binaries, this is a test assignment I need to practice. Any tips would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To figure out the most frequent course if the binary file is constructed of records in form of `exam` you need to read the file from the beginning to the end and then have some kind of counter for each course.

This can be done in many ways, e.g. encode each course name to a unique integer and then count ++1 every time you find the same course in the file or you could have a list of courses encountered then search the list - if you find the same course add to counter or add new node in the list with counter = 1